# Write tables from R using for loop, where table names contain the index of the loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, read.table, write.table

I have many .csv files in a folder, which are read with the following command:

```
for(i in 1:length(files)) {
assign(paste("tbl",i,sep=""),fread(file=files[i],skip=1,dec=",",sep="\t")) }
```

So I read every .csv file into different table, with the name tbl1, tbl2, tbl3...
I would like to write these tables into one file with the following for loop:

```
write.table(tbl1,file="data.csv", append=F, sep="\t", dec=",",col.names=T)

for (i in 2:length(files)) {
     val <- paste0("tbl",i)
     write.table(val, file="data.csv", append=T, sep="\t", dec=",", col.names=F)
}
```

But only paste "tbl2", "tbl3"... into the data.csv file instead of the data from tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste0` returns character as output, hence it's printing the tbl2,tbl3,.. you need to convert it into object, which can be done using `get`. If you want to use same format of code:

```
write.table(tbl1,file="data.csv", append=F, sep="\t", dec=",",col.names=T)

for (i in 2:length(files)) {
     val <- get(paste0("tbl",i))
     write.table(val, file="data.csv", append=T, sep="\t", dec=",", col.names=F)
}
```